# Android studio - creating plugin

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, intellij-plugin

I am trying to create a plugin for Android Studio. From the plugin itself I have the reference to the project and the files via IntelliJ API but I can't get to gradle's build variant which user selected.

Is it possible to somehow get the build variant selected by user from the plugin code itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you look at [BuildVariantView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/idea133/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/gradle/variant/view/BuildVariantView.java), line 147 down.

Basically (skipping the null checks):

```
ModuleManager moduleManager = ModuleManager.getInstance(myProject);
Module module = ...; // Depending on your requirements
AndroidFacet androidFacet = AndroidFacet.getInstance(module);
IdeaAndroidProject ideaAndroidProject = androidFacet.getIdeaAndroidProject();
Variant variant = ideaAndroidProject.getSelectedVariant();
```

Please be sure to check that the module is both Android and Gradle project - especially if you wish for your plugin to work with IntelliJ Idea.